# Серверное время в JS

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт который перенаправляет пользователя в определенное время, и он работает по клиентскому времени, и нужно задать клиенту серверное время. Или модифицировать скрипт.

Скрипт:

```
window.setInterval(function() {

var date = new Date();

var TimeStr = date.getHours()+":"+date.getMinutes();

if (TimeStr=="17:48")

window.location.href = "url";

},1000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Способ 1. Вместо if (TimeStr) используйте window.setTimeout(), в качестве второго параметра передайте вычисленное на стороне сервера оставшееся время до часа X

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var TimeStr = date.getHours()+":"+date.getMinutes();
    // какая-то еще логика
}, 1000);

window.setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.href = "url";
}, <?= $calculatedTimeout ?>);
```

Способ 2. Для вычисления значения TimeStr выполните ajax-запрос на сервер c передачей значения текущего timestamp браузера или часового пояса пользователя, на стороне сервера вычислите разницу и передайте обратно в браузер. в браузере воспользуйтесь этим значением

```
var stopTime = 0;
window.setInterval(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var TimeStr = date.getHours()+":"+date.getMinutes();
    if (stropTime > 0 && stopTime <= date.now()) {
         window.location.href = "url";
    }
    // какая-то еще логика
}, 1000);

$.get('/calcTime', {browserStamp: Date.now()}, function (answer) {
     stopTime = answer;
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, первый ответ помог.

Comment: @DaniilP, пожалуйста